# Unit test Android, getString from resource

Tags: android, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to do an unit test for an android app and I need to get a string from res.string resources. The class that I want to test is a POJO class. I am doing the app in two languages, due to this, I need to get a string from resource. The problem is that I cannot get the context or the activity, is possible? I know that with Instrumentation test I can do it, but I need to test some functions (white box test) before to do the instrumentation test (black box test). 
This is the function that I have to test:

```
public void setDiaByText(String textView) {
    getll_diaSeleccionado().clear();
    if (textView.contains(context.getResources().getString(R.string.sInicialLunes))) {
        getll_diaSeleccionado().add(0);
        getIsSelectedArray()[0] = true;
        getI_idiaSeleccionado()[0] =1;

    } else
    {
        getIsSelectedArray()[0] = false;
        getI_idiaSeleccionado()[0] =0;
    }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
@Test
public void setDiaByTextView() {
    String texto = "L,M,X,J,V,S,D";

    alertaPOJO.setDiaByText(texto);

    assertEquals(alertaPOJO.getIsSelectedArray()[0], true);
    assertEquals(alertaPOJO.getI_idiaSeleccionado()[0], 1);
}
```

It crash when try to do `context.getResources().getString(R.string.sInicialLunes))`

If I put 'Mon' instead of `context.getResources().getString(R.string.sInicialLunes))` or 'L' it work perfectly so, is possible to get the context or the activity in order to access to resource folder?

I am testing with Mockito and the setUp function is:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mContext = Mockito.mock(Alerta.class);
    Mockito.when(mContext.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(mContext);

    alertaPOJO = new AlertaPOJO();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) it's the same.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class YourClassUnitTest : TestCase() {

    @MockK
    private lateinit var resources: Resources

    @Before
    public override fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        every {
            resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age, YEARS, YEARS)
        } returns AGE
        every {
            resources.getString(
                R.string.surname,
                SURNAME
            )
        } returns TITLE

        // Assume you test this method that returns data class 
        // (fields are calculated with getQuantityString and getString)
        val data = getData(YEARS, SURNAME)

        assertEquals(AGE, data.age)
        assertEquals(TITLE, data.title)
    }

    companion object {
        const val YEARS = 10
        const val AGE = "$YEARS years"
        const val SURNAME = "Johns"
        const val TITLE = "Mr. $SURNAME"
    }
}
```

See also [Skip a parameter in MockK unit test, Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676134/skip-a-parameter-in-mockk-unit-test-kotlin) to get a result of string resources for any data.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using `Context` only for obtaining `String` resource, I would go by mocking only `getResources().getString()` part like this (see JUnit4 notation):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AlertaPOJOTest {

  @Mock
  Context mMockContext;

  @Test
  public void setDiaByTextView() {
     String texto = "L,M,X,J,V,S,D";
     when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.sInicialLunes))
       .thenReturn(INITIAL_LUNES);


     alertaPOJO.setDiaByText(texto);

     assertEquals(alertaPOJO.getIsSelectedArray()[0], true);
     assertEquals(alertaPOJO.getI_idiaSeleccionado()[0], 1);
   } 
}
```

There are many reasons to stay with JVM tests, most important one, they are running quicker.

Comment: getting this exception

Caused by: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentException: Failed to create proxy for class java.lang.String.
class java.lang.String is one of excluded classes

Comment: @tintomathew, for MockK see my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

Untested: would it work to use the below, and probably targetContext?

```
android {
   testOptions {
     unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a real android Context while you are using JVM unit test. For your case, maybe you can try Android Instrumentation Test, typically it is implemented in the "androidTest" directory of your project.

Comment: Thank you @Sherlock, I guess that it was the correct answer as I have read but I needed one confirmation due to I am a beginner in Android.

Answer (score 1):

I use [io.mockk](https://mockk.io/) library. For example:

```
mockkStatic(Resources::class)
every { Resources.getSystem().getString(any()) } returns "fake string"
every { Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics } returns mockk<DisplayMetrics>(relaxed = true)

mockkStatic(Color::class)
every { Color.parseColor(any()) } returns 0

mockkStatic(Log::class)
every { Log.v(any(), any()) } returns 0
every { Log.d(any(), any()) } returns 0
every { Log.i(any(), any()) } returns 0
every { Log.e(any(), any()) } returns 0
```