# How can I access a string resource from a test?

Tags: android, testing, junit, resources

I have a project in android. I want to test it in junit. In the resources, insinide `strings.xml` I have a string array called `labels_array`. How can I access (get) this string array from a test method in junit?

In the test class I have

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule mActivityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);
```

and

```
    @Test
    public void fooTest() {
        ActivityScenario scenario = mActivityRule.getScenario();
}
```

But How can I use these rule and method in order to acess the string array from inside the method `fooTest`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want to obtain the real value of the string array, you can use:

```java
final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
@ArrayRes final String[] labelsArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.labels_array);
```

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks! But now I get a warning about `context` that says "access can be provate".

Comment: That's because probably you defined it global. You can use the visibility you prefer (e.g. making it private)

Comment: Actually now I see that the first line works but the command `context.getResources()` throws an exception:
```
E/TestRunner: failed: iterateSpinnerItems(android.example.phonenumberspinnerWithTests.SpinnerSelectionTest)

    ----- begin exception -----

E/TestRunner: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f020000
```

Comment: Are you running your tests under androidTest?

Comment: Yes, it is in androidTest. Also, If it is matter somehow, I go according to the project and the test in section 3 in this tutorial (where I changed a little bit so it will work with newer API):
https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/en/Unit%202/61_p_use_espresso_to_test_your_ui.html#task3intro

Comment: I don't think I import the R file explicitely. My imports are:  `android.content.Context`, `androidx...`, `org.junit...`, `androidx.test...` and `org.hamcrest.Matchers...`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201229/discussion-between-giorgio-antonioli-and-j-doe).

Comment: After discussion @Giorgio turn my attension that I used `getContext()` instead of `getTargetContext()` and that solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with mock.I think one of below links may be the solution to your request.

https://medium.com/android-testing-daily/unit-testing-xml-resources-7387447f9ef7

or

[Unit test Android, getString from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576760/unit-test-android-getstring-from-resource)