# Skip a parameter in MockK unit test, Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-resources, mockk

I use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) library for unit testing.

Tested method contains strings that don't have meaning for a result. I want to check other variables, but have to define a behaviour of strings because they are used in tested methods.

For [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71675182/2914140),

```
every {
    resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age, 10, 10)
} returns "10 years"
every {
    resources.getString(
        R.string.surname,
        "surname"
    )
} returns "surname"
```

How can I omit parameters in these methods? So that I could pass any integer instead of 10, any string instead of "surname"? In this case a result of `resources.getString` won't have matter. I don't want to calculate a value of each parameter for a test. Just mock a behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `answers` instead of `returns` and have a plethora of options to return something depending on the input, e.g.

```
every {
    resources.getQuantityString(any(), any(), any())
} answers { "${arg<Int>(1)} years" }

every {
    resources.getString(any(), any())
} answers { secondArg() }
```

Check out [this table for the different parameters you can use in an answer](https://mockk.io/#answer-scope).

Comment: Thanks! Also we can add mocks for `resources.getString(any())` and `resources.getString(any(), any(), any())`.